# How to check if one textbox value should be less than another textbox value and also the sum of both values should not be greater than 1

Tags: javascript

How to check if one text box value should be less than another text box value and also the sum of both values should not be greater than 1 in javascript

Comment: Can you provide some code you are using currently?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example.

```js
function check()
{
   var input1 = Number(document.getElementById( "input1" ).value);
   var input2 = Number(document.getElementById( "input2" ).value);
   
   if ( input1 >= input2 || input1 + input2 != 1 )
   {
      console.log( "Error! Invalid value" );
   }
   else
   {
      console.log( "Success! Valid value" );
   }
}
```

```html
Input 1 (less value) <input id="input1" value="0"> <br><br>
Input 2 (more value) <input id="input2" value="1"> <br><br>

<button onclick="check()">Check</button>
```

Comment: @vineeta It is a noble quest, however it wasn't part of your original question and you haven't made any attempt yourself either. Please ask new question for new problem and make an attempt first as well. Good luck!

Comment: I have tried this thing,i was facing some issues while pasting my code in formatting that's why didn't posted here, as that is small solution only and also that thing i did just after posting my question so whatever remaining from my side that i asked in comment.

Comment: and i have resolved this yesterday only.So thanks for your help.